# AJAX request every 1 second without blocking the webpage, how to approach it

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a web app that will control a device that I have. The device has its own webserver (of which I have no control of) and it has its own language.
The way that I am controlling it is by doing ajax GET requests that are executing scripts on the device.

For example "http://127.0.0.1/nameOfScript?varName=varValue

I can also get data from the device through JSON, for example http://127.0.0.1/GetValuesJSON and it sends back the json object that I have created, so far so good.

My problem is that I want to continuously read data from the device and be able to send data at the same time, so I need to run the second URL every 0.5/1second, and be able to run the first URL whenever I want, the device and the webpage will be on a local network, security is not of importance.

Is it possible to do this within the HTML/JavaScript, if so, how? What do I have to research? Or do I need to use an additional webserver for the webpage that will handle this?

@abhinavxeon

^ Gave a solution to the problem, someone downvoted him and the comment was deleted, but the solution works and does exactly what I want it to do!
Here is the solution:

```
var interval;
function doSomething() {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'someurl',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {        
              $("#content").text(data)
              interval = setTimeout(doSomething, 1000);   
           }
       });
      }
doSomething();
```

Comment: yes you can do it html and javascript

Comment: @abhinavxeon okay, thats great, can you tell me how? What should I read up about?

Comment: FYI: Ajax is probably wrong solution for this, you want websockets if supported.

Comment: @epascarello I dont have an option, its complicated :)

Comment: you better do it with [https://socket.io/](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Guys, I dont have control over the webserver on the device, I have no idea what the server is, I have absolutely no access to it, I can just use whats given to me.

Comment: "Is it possible to do this within the HTML/JavaScript, if so, how?" — It's not clear what the problem is here. You already seem to know how to use Ajax. Are you asking how to create a timer in JS?

Comment: So you make calls. Nothing you can do, if it is struggling to keep up, then you need to adjust your read/write speeds.

Comment: @Quentin I am asking how to do this without blocking the webpage, and how to make the "read" requests go on, while at the same time be able to do the "write" requests. Im just having trouble wrapping my head around how to approach it

Comment: @Darkbound — What's blocking the webpage? What sort of problem are you having making read and write requests? Where's your [mcve] and clear problem statement (which would include basic debugging information like the results of monitoring the network tab of your browser's developer tools).

Comment: @Quentin I dont have them, what I was going to do was just surround the request with a loop, which obviously was not going to work and was going to block the page, being stuck in the loop, so my question is not "help me fix this", my question is "tell me what to research, so that i can start from somewhere" as I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: @Darkbound — Introductory JavaScript. If you want to do something every second then you use `setInterval` not `while` … and if you use Ajax, you don't turn the A part of (which you'd have to in order for a loop to work). (That said, a timeout on success instead of an interval would avoid having multiple requests in flight at the same time if the server didn't respond fast enough).

Comment: So you use a timeout, when the success is made, you do another timeout to call the function again....

Comment: check this article about requests using Ajax [polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket](https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9), you can have implemented in HTML/JS but this might cause too much load on the server, that's why people suggesting other implementation like sockets, I would suggest to check what is the options available from the server you are connecting to before going with.

Comment: @abhinavxeon your solution was correct and exactly what I needed.

Comment: please mark  it  as answer of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function yourfuncation() {
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'GETURL',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value     

            }
    });
}
```

**use setinterval**

```
var interval = setInterval(yourfunction, 1000);
```

**or you can go with this way**

```
    var interval;
function callAjax() {
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'increment.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                        $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value 
                        interval = setTimeout(callAjax, 1000);   
                }
        });
}
callAjax();
```

Comment: Both my requests are GET requests, not POST. Does it make a difference?

Comment: yup get call we use to fetch data and post to send

Comment: Hey, I am having a slight issue, it was working perfectly until I tried to add it as a function to an object - var GetData = { Type1Data: function() { your code}, Type2Data: function() { your code }} and so on, I have a few different calls that I have to make, it was working fine on "stand alone" functions, but now that I have extracted it into an object to make it easier to use for me, it stopped working, it is not auto-refreshing. Any idea how to fix that? Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/s5eoqu

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, apparently, "this" inside the ajax call refers to something entirely different, it worked with GetData.R, is there a way to still make it with this? Or I should stick to GetData.R

Answer (score 0):

So you need to poll the server. The way you normally would do it is with websockets. If you can not do websockets, then you have to rely on polling. To do that, you need to use setTimeout or setInterval.

Basic idea to poll a server would be

```
function grabData () {
  fetch('/your/endpoint/')
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something bad happened: ' + response.statusText );
      }
      return response.json();  // or text() if it is not JSON
    })
    .then((myJSON) => {
      console.log(myJSON)
      window.setTimeout(grabData, 2000) // call again after a delay
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('There was a problem', error);
    });
}
```

And you can make another function that does the update and call that when you need to send data up.